# AngularJS Elements in JS iframe1.location.href

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Working with AngularJS and I am coming across a annoying issue.  I am trying to use 1 link that opens links in two separate iframes. Everything works fine as intended except the actual links because I am using an onclick JS event to attempt to put these links in the proper frames. However it's not working, and placing an element from my angular script within this breaks the link.

This is what I have:

```
onclick="frame1.location.href='http://www.twitch.tv/{{user.username}}/chat'; frame2.location.href='http://twitch.tv/{{user.username}}/embed';"
```

It's not recognizing the {{user.username}} elements when they are inside the 'onclick'.

This did work when I had this page written in php (so I know it works), but went this route since it was too much on the server loads. This is the last bit I need to resolve and then my twitch page will be done.

Any thoughts on how to get this working how I need it to?

Twitch Boxs Script:

```
    <main ng-app="TwitchApi">
<section ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <table width="957" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td width="620">
                <iframe name="tbox" src="includes/first-load.php" frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' height='450' width='620'></iframe>
            </td>
            <td width="302" valign="top">
                <iframe name="cbox" src="includes/chat-load.php" scrolling='no' frameborder='0' scrolling='auto' height='450' width='300'></iframe>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div class="menu-box" align="left">
                    <span class="twitch-box">
                        <header>
                            <ul id="mainMenu">
                                <li data-display="allUsers" class="activeMenu">All</li>
                                <li data-display="onlineUsers">Online</li>
                                <li data-display="offlineUsers">Offline</li>
                                <li><a id="refresh" href="#"><img src="images/refresh.png" height=20 width=20></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </header>
                <div id="twitchreload">  
                    <ul id="grnstaff">
                        <a href="#" ng-click="changeSrc('cbox','http://www.twitch.tv/{{username}}/chat');changeSrc('tbox','http://www.twitch.tv/{{username}}/embed');" ng-repeat="user in profile | orderBy:random">
                        <li  id="oncheck-{{user.username}}" ng-style="{ 'background-color' : (user.streaming) ? '#ccffcc' : '#EAEAEA' }">
                            <img ng-src="{{user.logo}}" err-src="images/twitch-default.jpg" class="pic"/>
                            <span class="name">{{user.name}}</span>
                            <span class="status"><i class="{{user.status}}"></i></span>
                            <span class="title">{{user.streamTitle}} <i class="{{user.tv}}"></i> {{user.viewers}}</span>
                        </li>
                        </a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have all of your code but I believe this is what you will need.

Live Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/LGdyLN

HTML(you will need to use ng-click instead of onclick with angular):

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="user">

  <p ng-click="changeSrc('frame1','http://www.twitch.tv/{{username}}/chat');changeSrc('frame2','http://www.twitch.tv/{{username}}/embed');">
    Click Me!
  </p>

  <iframe id="frame1" src=""></iframe>

  <iframe id="frame2" src=""></iframe>



</div>
```

Angular/JavaScript:

```
angular.module("app",[]).controller('user', ['$scope', function($scope){

 //the user name to bind to the url
 $scope.username = "Larry";

 //function to change the src attribute of the iframe
 $scope.changeSrc = function(id,url){

var frame = document.getElementById(id); 

   frame.src = url;

 };


}]);
```

Comment: I had that too but it didn't work. It didn't seem to even recognize the links at all.

Comment: I updated it with a fully working example. I am assuming your html structure is similar to what I posted.

Comment: Your example works wonderful, but for some reason it's still not working with mine.  I also made sure to add the function as well. I edited my original post with the full section that I am working with.

Comment: Ok, looks like that was my mistake.  I forgot to add the 'id' - I just had the frame 'name' in the code.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I am glad I could help.  Your project looks interesting.